# Изменение кодировки строки C#

Tags: c#, html, парсер, кодировка

Получаю строку из файла HTML и вывожу в консоль, но кодировка в виде иероглифов.
Пытаюсь ее изменить следующим образом:

```
        var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/div/span");
        string str = node[2].InnerText;
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
        Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);

        byte[] utf8Byte = utf8.GetBytes(str);
        byte[] win1251Byte = Encoding.Convert(utf8, win1251, utf8Byte);
        str = win1251.GetString(win1251Byte);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Но это не помогает. Где может быть ошибка? Спасибо.

Начальная часть кода страницы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для примера, вот что отображается в консоли (Должно быть написано ID объекта):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой файл выгружается из программы, файл закинул в облако, вот [ссылка](https://fex.net/108783394161?fileId=551023115)

Comment: А ваша html страница точно в utf-8? Можете привести тест страницы и текст, который у вас в консоле?

Comment: Выводится ли строка корректно если ее прописать прямо в коде ( `String str = @"строка"`)? Хочется убедиться что проблема не связана с консолью.

Comment: Ваши манипуляции бессмысленны. Строки (string) в .NET имеют кодировку Unicode (UTF16) и никакую другую иметь не могут! Правильную кодировку нужно указывать _при получении_ данных.

Comment: Покажите, как загружаете данные в объект `doc`.

Comment: HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(path); я пытаюсь это делать через HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: Было бы проще, если вы приложили бы ссылку на страницу, чтобы мы могли воспроизвести вашу проблему.

Comment: Попробуйте изменить шрифт консоли

Comment: Этот файл выгружается из программы. Файл закинул в облаку и ссылку добавил в основное описание

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Укажите кодировку при загрузке документа

```
doc.Load(path, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

1. Смотрим в отладчике, правильно ли отображается полученная строка.
2. Возможно у вас в консоли используется DOS кодировка 866, а не 1251. Это можно проверить командой mode в командной строке.